# Akka streams - resuming graph with broadcast and zip after failure

Tags: scala, stream, akka, akka-stream

I have a flow graph with broadcast and zip inside. If something (regardless what is it) fails inside this flow, I'd like to drop the problematic element passed to it and resume. I came up with the following solution:

```
val flow = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val dangerousFlow = Flow[Int].map {
    case 5 => throw new RuntimeException("BOOM!")
    case x => x
  }
  val safeFlow = Flow[Int]
  val bcast = builder.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
  val zip = builder.add(Zip[Int, Int])

  bcast ~> dangerousFlow ~> zip.in0
  bcast ~> safeFlow ~> zip.in1

  FlowShape(bcast.in, zip.out)
})

Source(1 to 9)
  .via(flow)
  .withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(Supervision.restartingDecider))
  .runWith(Sink.foreach(println))
```

I'd expect it to print:

```
(1,1)
(2,2)
(3,3)
(4,4)
(5,5)
(6,6)
(7,7)
(8,8)
(9,9)
```

However, it deadlocks, printing only:

```
(1,1)
(2,2)
(3,3)
(4,4)
```

We've done some debugging, and it turns out it applied the "resume" strategy to its children, which caused `dangerousFlow` to resume after failure and thus to demand an element from `bcast`. `bcast` won't emit an element until `safeFlow` demands another element, which actually never happens (because it's waiting for demand from `zip`).

Is there a way to resume the graph regardless of what went wrong inside one of the stages?

Answer (score 4):

I think you understood the problem well. You saw that, when your element `5` crashes `dangerousFlow`, you should also stop the element `5` that is going through `safeFlow` because if it reaches the `zip` stage, you have the problem you describe. I don't know how to solve your problem between the `broadcast` and `zip` stages, but what about pushing the problem further, where it is easier to handle?

Consider using the following `dangerousFlow`:

```
import scala.util._
val dangerousFlow = Flow[Int].map {
  case 5 => Failure(new RuntimeException("BOOM!"))
  case x => Success(x)
}
```

Even in case of problem, `dangerousFlow` would still emit data. You can then `zip` as you are currently doing and would just need to add a `collect` stage as last step of your graph. On a flow, this would look like:

```
Flow[(Try[Int], Int)].collect {
  case (Success(s), i) => s -> i
}
```

Now if, as you wrote, you really expect it to output the `(5, 5)` tuple, use the following:

```
Flow[(Try[Int], Int)].collect {
  case (Success(s), i) => s -> i
  case (_, i)          => i -> i
}
```